# Crystal Reporting in VS2010 for Desktop Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Dear fellows I am 6 to 8 months old programmer and I do some plain programming like I've created point of sale/purchase inventory etc.

But in my whole programming career, I've never done crystal reporting, I need to know how can I do **Crystal Reporting** in C# in **VS2010** for Desktop Application (like inventory software).

Please guide me in this regards or suggest me any link from where I can learn **Crystal Reporting** from very basic.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need Crystal Reports specifically? Have you investigated Microsoft Reporting (RDL / RDLC)? I ask because Crystal is not free and is not significantly better than the MS Reporting, which is free in basic usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have installed Crystal Reports for Visual Studio which can be found here. http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
2. I usually create views to fetch the data that I want to be displayed. You can add the views to your dataset.
3. You can make a new Crystal Reports by going to Add New Item -> Reports -> Crystal Reports.
4. In Visual Studio, while your new report is still in view, you should see the the Crystal Reports Menu, click on it and then click on Field Explorer.
5. You can then right click on Database Field to setup and set the datasource location of your report. The fields will then be in view to drag and drop.
6. You will need to create a report viewer to see the report and code appropriately for it.

There are many articles on how to create CR reports in Visual Studio like these two. http://www.codemag.com/Article/0207021

This one may be based on a ASP.NET project but the procedure for creating one is basically the same. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual

This is a good one to follow step by step.